# Regarding C (not C++) does doing math in comparison statements help or hurt efficiency? What about declaring pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, math, comparison

Since people can't seem to read I'm editing the question, and debating removal. I had simplified code representing some logic I'm working on optimizing in a large and very old project. I asked them to not focus so much on the code as much as the concepts of coding in C... I had to use code to help ask question because I'm not sure how to word properly otherwise.

Regarding C (not C++) does doing math in comparison statements help or hurt efficiency? What about declaration of pointers? SORRY can't give code examples as the syntax will be nitpicked to hell before I can get an answer.

Comment: If your question is about C and not C++, *don't tag C++*.

Comment: Why is `int *HSCKills` pointer initialised to an `int`? Enable compiler warnings.

Comment: Later, `HSCKills++;`is incrementing the pointer, not `.kills`.

Comment: Well I mean the second two, if written "correctly" would involve extra dereferences, so... my money's on the first being faster. You could always profile it, and or look at the assembly output ( the asm output will likely be more comparable for m2 & m3 ).

Comment: In Third Example, `int HSC_Ratio;` and the next three are only used once at most. And `if(SSC_Diff > HSC_Diff)` might not even be executed, so you needlesly precalculate values so simple to compute they are probably not even stored in memory.

Comment: I think, generally, you would be better off focusing your efforts on writing clean, efficient code that is easy to read and maintain. Let the compiler worry about optimization. I doubt that the runtimes of any of the methods you listed above would differ by more than a fraction of a microsecond.

Comment: Write. Test. If performance requirements not met, profile. Use the profiling to target regions that can most benefit from extra attention to speed. Improve those areas. Test. Repeat.

Comment: The most obvious optimization would be to cache death/kill ratios in the client structure since they are used for sorting. Then the question becomes essentially moot for this particular case.

Comment: Why don't you just test these methods under heavy load instead of asking other people to guess the result? It can be really hard to know in advance where the bottlenecks are in a real situation.

Comment: The question is in regards to overall concepts, not nit picky specifics. I can run code analysis and measure load, but it's a LARGE project, I'd like to just understand best practices.

Comment: Best practice is as outlined by squeamish. If you post code here, expect it to be torn to bits if you throw together something resembling your code.

Answer (score 2):

Performing comparisons between expression results or storing the values into local variables before the comparison usually does not make much of a difference, except when the computation can be avoided.  Here is a classic example:

```
int count_char(const char *s, char c) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        if (s[i] == c)
           count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Computing the length of the string for each iteration is very inefficient.  Computing it once in the loop initial phase is better:

```
int count_char(const char *s, char c) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(s); i < len; i++) {
        if (s[i] == c)
           count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Yet a different approach with pointers (as mentioned in your question) may prove even more efficient:

```
int count_char(const char *s, char c) {
    int count = 0;
    while (*s) {
        if (*s++ == c)
           count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

And here is a tighter version, albeit less readable:

```
int count_char(const char *s, char c) {
    int count = 0;
    while (*s) {
        count += (*s++ == c);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Note that all of the above functions should use `size_t` instead of `int` for the `i`, `len` and `count` variables as, on some platforms, the length of the string could be larger than the maximum value of type `int`.

Note also that a very good optimizing compiler could produce similar and efficient code for all versions as `strlen()` is a pure function and the contents of `s` can be determined to remain constant during the execution of the function, but it is not necessarily true for more complicated examples.

Comment: Perfect thank you. What I was looking for.

Comment: @Logik: you can accept this answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.